# Using GSM and GPRS at the same time

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, gprs

I am sending data continuously to a remote server using the [SIM300](http://probots.co.in/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=284) [GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM)/[GPRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service) modem connected to an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). At the same time I want to check if I have received an [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) on the [SIM card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module).

In the setup function I have configured the modem to GPRS mode and executing the AT+CIPSEND continuously to send data in the main loop program. In my interrupt routine I want to check for the SMS notification using the AT+CNMI command. So is it OK to check for SMS notifications while the modem is operating in GPRS mode or is there a clash of SMS and GPRS mode because the interrupt modem is running asynchronously along with the main program?

Answer (score 1):

While I shall not guarantee that this SIM300 modem is without any errors, there should be no problem checking SMS while GPRS traffic is ongoing.

The `AT+CNMI` command is just a command for reporting new SMS messages arrived on a serial interface, which is a local TE-TA<sup>1</sup> issue and independent of network activity (which by the way fully handles sending/receiving SMS messages even when there is ongoing voice or data calls (circuit switched or packet switched)). You have to receive the +CNMI UR codes on a different serial interface than the one which is sending data though.

For more details about `AT+CNMI` I recommend that you look into the [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) specification.

<sup>1</sup>
TE: Terminal Equipment, e.g. PC/microprocessor.
TA: Terminal Adapter, e.g. modem.